# Get sql data type fom column c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, compare, sqldatatypes, dac

I'm using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Compare to compare two database and create a custom script.

My problem is to get the sql data type of the column from the object TsqlObject.

I can acess at lot proprerties from the column except the sql data type.

Comment: This might be helpful https://sqlserverfunctions.wordpress.com/category/dacfx-2/

Comment: Thx, it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property from the datadeader

```
    sqlReader.GetFieldType(intPositionalFieldIndex)
```